# How to get a right regex to get output like i want

Tags: regex, perl

Hello i am using perl and now i don't know how to get ouput like i want. I want only print all digit beetween DIGIT below is my code i hope somebody here can help me to find a right regex.

Please help me ... here my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $string = "<TR><TD COLSPAN=2 VALIGN=TOP>Please enter the random key shown below:<TR><TD>&nbsp;<TD VALIGN=TOP><FONT SIZE=+1><FONT COLOR=WHITE>...</FONT>4<FONT COLOR=WHITE>...</FONT>5<FONT COLOR=WHITE>...</FONT>4<FONT COLOR=WHITE>..</FONT>4<FONT COLOR=WHITE>..</FONT>2<FONT COLOR=WHITE>..</FONT>2</FONT></TR>";

if ($string =~  m,</FONT>(\d)<FONT COLOR=WHITE,i) {
    print "$1\n";  #output 454422
} else {
     print "Wrong Regex! \n";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It's good that you showed your code. Now, you say the output is not like you want it... so, how do you want it? What is wrong with it? Another thing: You will probably have people telling you not to parse HTML with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `/g` flag for "global match", which matches all occurrences of the pattern, as opposed to just the first one.

```
while ( $string =~  m,</FONT>(\d)<FONT COLOR=WHITE,ig ) {
    print "$1\n";
} # output 45442
```

Note that the last `2` won't match your pattern. It would if you changed it to:

```
m,</FONT>(\d)(?:</FONT|<FONT COLOR=WHITE),ig
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your desired output is the comment line `#output 454422`. To get that, you need to wrap your regex in a `while`-loop and add the `/g` [modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers). Right now, it's only matching once.

```
my $string =
"<TR><TD COLSPAN=2 VALIGN=TOP>Please enter the random key shown below:<TR><TD>&nbsp;<TD VALIGN=TOP><FONT SIZE=+1><FONT COLOR=WHITE>...</FONT>4<FONT COLOR=WHITE>...</FONT>5<FONT COLOR=WHITE>...</FONT>4<FONT COLOR=WHITE>..</FONT>4<FONT COLOR=WHITE>..</FONT>2<FONT COLOR=WHITE>..</FONT>2</FONT></TR>";

while ( $string =~ m,</FONT>(\d)<FONT COLOR=WHITE,ig ) {
  if ($1) {
    print "$1\n";
  #output 454422
  } else {

    print "Wrong Regex! \n";
  }
}
```